# How to make iOS app remember the image that a user chose from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have a UIImage covering the whole view and an option to set an image from their photo library.

My problem is every time I close the app completely, the UIImage reverts back to the default image.

Here is my code if you need to look at it:

```
 @IBAction func wallpaperMenuPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary;
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        // The app is running on an iPad, so you have to wrap it in a UIPopOverController
        self.imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)//4
        imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = wallpaperMenu
        imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = (sender as! UIButton).bounds

    } else {
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary;
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false


        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ViewController` must conform `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

You need to declare this variable on the top of your ViewController:

```
let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

Then you can get the image from `PhotoLibrary` by:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
     imageView.image = image
     let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
     userDefault.setObject(imageData, forKey: "khuong")
}
```

And in your viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageData = userDefault.objectForKey("khuong") as? NSData
    if let imageData = imageData {
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got those already there, I can get the image but it doesn't remember it for next time

Answer (score 1):

That's how you might have designed.When you have created UIImageView,you would have set up the default image in storyboard or xib or through code.

As you start the app,this screen starts from UI created in xib/storyboard/code and also whatever default image set up in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear.

Whatever image you have picked and saved will be lost once you close the app unless you changed your default image to the selected one.Make sure your default image is taken from NSUserDefaults which will persist between application launches

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSUserDefaults`  to store your selected image

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
    let myImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myImage, forKey: "myPhoto")
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }
```